# Symfony 2.8 clear cache and timed out

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I have this error when I clear the cache :
[SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation timed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMam2.png)

I'm using symfony 2.8, on a docker-compose (db, php, phpmyadmin, nginx)
I don't have any problem to connect my php docker to my db docker and the site works. But I would like to fix this issue.
I tried to increase the interactive_timeout thanks to this post "https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/how-to-change-the-mysql-timeout-on-a-server/" nothing change...

I have the same error when I update the project with composer. If someone have an idea...

config.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
    - { resource: "@UserBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }

parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }

    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

swiftmailer:
     transport: "%mailer_transport%"
     host:      "%mailer_host%"
     username:  "%mailer_user%"
     password:  "%mailer_password%"
     spool:     { type: memory }

# FOS UserBundle Configuration
fos_user:
     db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
     firewall_name: main
     user_class: UserBundle\Entity\User
     registration:
         form:
             type: UserBundle\Form\RegistrationType
     confirmation:
         from_email:
             address:        server@mail.com # put a valid mail address
             sender_name:    Confimation link
         enabled: false # pass to true to enable sending mail inscriptions
         template:   FOSUserBundle:Registration:email.txt.twig
    profile:
         form:
             type: UserBundle\Form\ProfileFormType
    resetting:
         email:
             template:   UserBundle:Reset:password_resetting.email.twig
             from_email:
                  address:        server@mail.com # put a valid mail address
                  sender_name:    Reset link
```

parameters.yml :

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
    database_host: 172.18.0.2
    database_port: 3306
    database_name: symfony
    database_user: user
    database_password: user_password
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    secret: my_secret
```

security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:
            - ROLE_USER

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                login_path: /
                use_forward: false
                check_path: fos_user_security_check
                failure_path: null
                default_target_path: /
                remember_me: true

            remember_me:
                secret:      %secret%
                lifetime: 3000
                path:     /
                domain:   ˜
            logout:
                path: fos_user_security_logout
                target: /
            anonymous:    true
            switch_user:  true
```

And then my docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '2'

services:
    db:
        image: mysql
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        volumes:
            - "./.data/db:/var/lib/mysql"
            - "./script:/stack"
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: user_password
        command:
            - "/stack/localdb-run.sh"
    php:
        build: php7-fpm
        ports:
            - 9000:9000
        links:
             - db:mysqldb
        volumes:
            - ./symfony:/var/www/symfony
            - ./logs/symfony:/var/www/symfony/app/logs
    nginx:
        build: nginx
           ports:
               - 80:80
        links:
           - php
        volumes_from:
           - php
        volumes:
           - ./logs/nginx/:/var/log/nginx
phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:4.6.4-1
    ports:
        - "8080:80"
    links:
        - db
```

Comment: Can you post your parameter.yml and your config.yml pls ?

Comment: done :) @DOZ ....

Comment: I think the problem comes from docker not Symfony. Could you send your `docker-compose.json` please ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I added the docker-compose.yml :) @Roukmoute

Comment: In fact your website with DB works but not your command isn't it?

Have you tried to replace `database_host: 172.18.0.2` with `database_host: mysqldb` ?

Do not work with IP, but with [container name][1].

I've found [this][2], don't know if that can help you.


  [1]: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/containername
  [2]: http://serverfault.com/questions/736090/timeout-error-on-mariadb-in-docker-container

Comment: @Roukmoute Exactly, my DB works but I've an error only when I want to clear the cache... and when I run a composer update (but I have the same error). Replacing with mysqldb does'nt work...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you type anything like this in your command: `php bin/console cache:clear`

But You use Docker, so you must launch docker with this command.

And you have not `phpcli` in your docker-compose.json :)

Add it and launch this command example: `docker-compose run --rm phpcli bin/console cache:clear`

Comment: Thank for the answer but I have the same problem when I launch this command inside the docker (with >> docker-compose exec php bash) :( @Roukmoute